# A non-denumerable set has non-denumerably many  cluster points?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I can´t prove this fact in $\mathbb{R}$.  I want to know how general this result is. (What topological properties are needed to prove it?) 
Let $X$ be a non-denumerable subset of the real numbers. How can I  prove that the set of limit points of $X$ is also non-denumerable?

Comment: I believe the common term is non-denumerable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let Y be the set of limit points of X.

Since X-Y does not contain any of its limit points, X-Y is discrete.

We need that all discrete subsets are (at-most-)countable.

With that, since $X\subseteq (X-Y)\cup Y$, $\; $ Y is not (at-most-)countable.

A discrete subset of a separable metric space is always (at-most-)countable.

Comment: Beautiful, and thank!